# What's the probability of choosing a sequence of $4$ numbers, in a particular order?

Tags: probability

I'm having a dispute with my friend about the following calculation. I was randomly assigned a new phone number that ends in the four digits which represent his birthday ($8479$).  We are trying to calculate what is the probability of those digits being assigned, in that order?

So far, I've broken it down into two events:

- $A=$  Probability of being assigned $8$,$4$,$7$ and $9$ in any order $= \frac1{10000} = 0.0001$
- $B=$  Probability of those numbers being in a specific order $= \frac1{n!} = \frac1{24} \approx 0.041667 $
- $P(A,B)=$  probability that given the $4$ digits are selected, then they
  are in the right order $= 0.0001 \times 0.041667 \approx 4.16667 \times 10^{-6}$, or odds of $\frac1{240000}$.

Have I calculated this correctly? If not, what's the right way to calculate it?  I've spend a fair bit of time trying to google this with no luck, and sadly it has been a very  long  time since my university probbability class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of being assigned $8479$ **in that order** is $10^{-4}$.

(We are making the assumption that numbers are assigned "at random" with all strings between $0000$ and $9999$ are equally likely. That may be false. Perhaps "nice" numbers are reserved for businesses willing to pay extra for them.)

Answer (score 2):

The calculation of $A$ is wrong. You want to keep the calculation and throw away $A$.

Think of it like this: What is the probability that the first digit is right? What is the probability that the second digit is right? What is the probability that all of them are right?

Comment: Providing an explanation is a good thing that I failed to do.

Answer (score 2):

Or to put it another way--there are $10^4$ numbers 'between' 0000 and 9999 and you want ONE.  So it's $\cfrac{1}{10^{4}}$.

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

The probability of four numbers being selected is equal to the number of ways that the four numbers can be arranged in a specific order, divided by the total number of arrangements of those four numbers. Let us first look at the latter: the total number of ways to arrange 8, 4, 7, 9 in any order is $10^4$, since you have place for 4 digits and each place has a choice of 10 different digits (from 0 to 9). Then, if we look at the total number of ways of having the numbers 8, 4, 7, 9 in that order, then we have places for 4 digits, but in each place, there is only 1 digit that we can choose from (i.e. the number that should be assigned to the first place is 8). So, the total arrangements for this is $1^4 =1$.Therefore, the probability of having those four numbers in that order is equal to: $ \frac{1}{10^4} $ = 0.0001.